# Setting queue in Hadoop cluster using Capacity Scheduler

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, job-scheduling

I tried to set up 3 queues. For that I configured CapacityScheduler.xml as shown below. But after this the jobtracker is shutting down. I added the names of these queues to the mapred-site.xml also. Anyone know the reason.

```
enter code here

*<!-- queue: BatchJobs-Queue -->
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.BatchJobsQueue.capacity</name>
  <value>70</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.BatchJobsQueue.supports-priority</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.BatchJobsQueue.minimum-user-limit-percent</name>
  <value>20</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.BatchJobsQueue.user-limit-factor</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.BatchJobsQueue.maximum-initialized-active-tasks</name>
  <value>200000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.BatchJobsQueue.maximum-initialized-active-tasks-per-user</name>
  <value>100000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.BatchJobsQueue.init-accept-jobs-factor</name>
  <value>10</value>
</property>

    enter code here

<!-- queue: AdHocJobs-Queue -->
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.AdHocJobsQueue.capacity</name>
  <value>20<value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.AdHocJobsQueue.supports-priority</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.AdHocJobsQueue.minimum-user-limit-percent</name>
  <value>20</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.AdHocJobsQueue.user-limit-factor</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.AdHocJobsQueue.maximum-initialized-active-tasks</name>
  <value>200000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.AdHocJobsQueue.maximum-initialized-active-tasks-per-user</name>
  <value>100000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.AdHocJobsQueue.init-accept-jobs-factor</name>
  <value>10</value>
</property>

    enter code here

<!-- queue: MyQueue  -->
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.MyQueue.capacity</name>
  <value>10<value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.MyQueue.supports-priority</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.MyQueue.minimum-user-limit-percent</name>
  <value>20</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.MyQueue.user-limit-factor</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.MyQueue.maximum-initialized-active-tasks</name>
  <value>200000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.MyQueue.maximum-initialized-active-tasks-per-user</name>
  <value>100000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.MyQueue.init-accept-jobs-factor</name>
  <value>10</value>
</property>*

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of your job tracker log?

Assuming you're running linux try running this:

```
ls -lrt /var/log/hadoop/mapred/ | grep jobtracker | tail -n1 | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -I{} tail -n40 /var/log/hadoop/mapred/{}
```